# Get element's xpath in javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am developing in javascript and I would need to get the xpath of the element clicked.
I know that in order to get the id we can do :

```
element.onclick = function(event)
{
    var target_id = event.target.id;
}
```

How could I do to get the xpath ?

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - Get the DOM path of the clicked <a>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728558/jquery-get-the-dom-path-of-the-clicked-a)

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32623171/502860

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: @JensErat that's different than XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to access an element with XPath. For example you can access it by node name or by the value of one of it's attributes or child nodes. So you can not expect that javascript gives you exactly one of them.

But as you have the id, the simplest xpath query to access the element would be:

```
//*[@id="THE_ID"]
```

Comment: I don't need to get element with his xpath, I would need to get the xpath of an element clicked.

Comment: Yeah, I know (you already have it). Please read the answer again. The *path* you are looking for is `//*[@id="THE_ID"]`

Comment: Sounds like you are searching for the `DOM Path` rather then an XPath expression. (Although a DOM path is a valid XPath expression as well) Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728558/jquery-get-the-dom-path-of-the-clicked-a)

Comment: Yeah, that's I want. I think your explanation will help me to find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
function getXPath(node){
    if(node.hasAttribute("id")){
        return '//' + node.tagName + '[@id="' + node.id + '"]';
    }

    if(node.hasAttribute("class")){
        return '//' + node.tagName + '[@class="' + node.getAttribute("class") + '"]';
    }

    var old = '/' + node.tagName;
    var new_path = this.xpath(node.parentNode) + old;

    return new_path;
}
```

Comment: This code sure doesn't work as is. What is `this.xpath`? This fails when node becomes DOCUMENT as it does not have a hasAttribute method.