# Playwright: Get full XPATH of selected element

Tags: python, python-3.x, puppeteer, playwright, playwright-python

I want to retrieve the full XPATH (`\\html\div\...`) of an element I have previously found via e.g. `page.waitForSelector()` or `page.querySelector()`.

How would I do this with Playwright? I was not able to find any built-in solutions for this.

NOTE: I am using `playwright-python`, but would be open to implementing JS solutions for this - given it will work.

Template (taken from `https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python` sample code):

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("http://whatsmyuseragent.org/")
        element = page.waitForSelector(selector="text=\"My IP Address: 192.168.0.1\"")
        # HERE: retrieve full XPATH of 'element'
        browser.close()
```

### EDIT:

`@hardkoded` suggested the answers to [this question (Get element's xpath in javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731640/get-elements-xpath-in-javascript) as a solution, but sadly the mentioned solution does not work for my use-case as I would need to retrieve the entire XPATH of an element, and shortcuts like `//*[@id="THE_ID"]` will not work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get element's xpath in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731640/get-elements-xpath-in-javascript)

Comment: @hardkoded Sadly not, as I would need to retrieve the complete XPATH of an element and shortcuts like `//*[@id="THE_ID"]` sadly will not work for my purposes. Thank you for linking the question though!

Comment: Just as a hint. Look for JavaScript snippets that you can run from puppeteer. Puppeteer doesn't have anything for that out of the box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the XPath position of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454526/how-to-calculate-the-xpath-position-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

For Typescript/Javascript there is [playwright-dompath](https://github.com/alexferrari88/playwright-DOMPath) which you can install with:

```
npm install playwright-dompath
```

Basically you just call the xPath function with the element you selected, and you get back the full xPath.
Under the hood, it uses the same functions from Chrome DevTools.