# jQuery - on click with * selector trigger too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to record down the full css path on every element click by user, I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728558/get-the-dom-path-of-the-clicked-a/16742828) answer to create a function that get css path of the clicked element

```
$('body').on('click',"*",function(){
    var rightArrowParents = [];
    $(this).parents().addBack().not('html').each(function(e) {
        var entry = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

        if($(this).attr('id')){
            entry += "#" + $(this).attr('id');
        }

        if (this.className) {
        entry += "." + this.className.replace(/ /g, '.');
        }

        rightArrowParents.push(entry);
    });
    console.log(rightArrowParents.join(" > "));
})
```

but I notice that this function is called so many times when I click on an element which is wrap by multiple element,

for example when I click on h1:

```
body > div.sample1.sample2 > div.sample3.sample4 > h1.test1.test2.test3

body > div.sample1.sample2 > div.sample3.sample4

body > div.sample1.sample2
```

when I add `return false` after console.log, it will only output the full css path of h1, which is the expected result, but if I do this, some element will not work properly such as `<a>` will not redirect to another website

below is what I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sample1 sample2">
        <div class="sample3 sample4">
            <h1 class="test1 test2 test3">some example text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="test1 test2 test3">some sample text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sample1 sample2">
        <div class="sample3 sample4">
            <a class="test1 test2 test3" href="https://www.google.com/">henlo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('body').on('click',"*",function(){
                var rightArrowParents = [];
                $(this).parents().addBack().not('html').each(function(e) {
                    var entry = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

                    if($(this).attr('id')){
                        entry += "#" + $(this).attr('id');
                    }

                    if (this.className) {
                    entry += "." + this.className.replace(/ /g, '.');
                    }

                    rightArrowParents.push(entry);
                });
                console.log(rightArrowParents.join(" > "));
                //can't do this, since it will make some element malfunction
                //return false
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

what should I do to make the jQuery work properly?

Comment: This is because of _event propagation_ which is a standard feature of jQuery.  jQuery is, in fact, working as it should.  You can read more about event propagation (including how to resolve your issue) here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may look a bit hacky, but it gets the job done. along these lines there may also be a more elegant solution (like to compare some property of the event for cancellation.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('body').on('click',"*",function(e) {
        // mark the event as seen and cancel it it was seen
        if (e.seen) return;
        e.seen = true;
        
        var rightArrowParents = [];
        $(this).parents().addBack().not('html').each(function(i, o) {
            var entry = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

            if($(this).attr('id')){
                entry += "#" + $(this).attr('id');
            }

            if (this.className) {
            entry += "." + this.className.replace(/ /g, '.');
            }

            rightArrowParents.push(entry);
        });
        console.log(rightArrowParents.join(" > "));
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sample1 sample2">
        <div class="sample3 sample4">
            <h1 class="test1 test2 test3">some example text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="test1 test2 test3">some sample text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sample1 sample2">
        <div class="sample3 sample4">
            <a class="test1 test2 test3" href="https://www.google.com/">henlo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question clearly, all you need to do is add an event parameter to your function `function(e)`, then use `e.stopPropagation()` at the end to prevent it from going through the event handlers of the parent elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sample1 sample2">
    <div class="sample3 sample4">
      <h1 class="test1 test2 test3">some example text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="test1 test2 test3">some sample text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="sample1 sample2">
    <div class="sample3 sample4">
      <a class="test1 test2 test3" href="https://www.google.com/">henlo</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('body').on('click', "*", function(e) {
        var rightArrowParents = [];
        $(this).parents().addBack().not('html').each(function() {
          var entry = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

          if ($(this).attr('id')) {
            entry += "#" + $(this).attr('id');
          }

          if (this.className) {
            entry += "." + this.className.replace(/ /g, '.');
          }

          rightArrowParents.push(entry);
        });
        console.log(rightArrowParents.join(" > "));
        
        e.stopPropagation();
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```